# RPC_E_SERVERFAULT error on oppening an Excel file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, vba

I'm trying to open an Excel file to get and set some values. Unfortunately, I have no choice, I must to work with Excel.

```
Dim xAp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim xWkb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook

xWkb = xAp.Workbooks.Open("c:\uploads\teste.xls")
```

Always I have this exception: `(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))`

Need I Excel installed in server machine to open Excel files? I don't think so, because when I create a new application and workbook throught code, all things go right, but... its a possibility...

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need Excel installed on the server to open Excel files using COM Interop.  It's not recommended, and I would recommend using a 3rd party library to access data in Excel files.  You can also try and put the data into an easier-to-work with CSV, though you stated this might not be possible.

Comment: Would you please recommend me a 3rd party library to do this task? If it's free, better... And do you know why I can create a new Excel file and work with it and I can't just open an existing file into the object? thanks...

Comment: I would recommend spreadsheetgear, though it's not free.  Unsure of how you can create the file without Excel being installed, are you using File.Create?

Comment: Server-side automation is NOT supported:  See this KB: support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757, my advice would be to use ClosedXML